# how to destroy jquery dialog when pressing escape?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

how to destroy jquery dialog when pressing escape?

Is there a way to add a code like that:
    $.dialog('destroy');

inside of a close event?
Here is the close event: It seens that the last 'else' has a hide method and this is the guy. But can´t destroy anything there:

```
close: function( event ) {
    var that = this,
        maxZ, thisZ;

    if ( !this._isOpen ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( false === this._trigger( "beforeClose", event ) ) {
        return;
    }

    this._isOpen = false;

    if ( this.overlay ) {
        this.overlay.destroy();
    }

    if ( this.options.hide ) {
        this._hide( this.uiDialog, this.options.hide, function() {
            that._trigger( "close", event );                
        });
    } else {
        this.uiDialog.hide();
        this._trigger( "close", event );
    }
```

Comment: you just want to close the dialog? if you just want to close the dialog just do like $.dialog({ closeOnEscape: true });

Comment: No, this is set by default. If I close on escape, the content still there. It just hide the content. Next time the user creates the dialog my tab creates with problems. I found a solution with the buttons. I just add .dialog('destroy') and it really remove everything from DOM. I want this behavior associated with the close event so when I press escape, I get everything vanished from DOM. I´ve edit my question.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the contents when you create the dialog? Then you can use the closeOnEscape method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way of doing this editing directly the close event since I want this behavior in the whole application.

From:

```
else {
    this.uiDialog.hide();
    this._trigger( "close", event );
}
```

To:

```
else {
    this.uiDialog.remove();
    this._trigger( "close", event );
}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Just as a note, you probably shouldn't edit plugins directly, as it makes bugs incredibly difficult to find in the future and renders documentation of the plugin useless. It also would make it hard for someone on SO to debug, if you happen to post a question here.

Answer (score 5):

The most elegant way I could find is to listen to the dialog's close event, and destroy it.

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({
    buttons: {
        OK: function(event) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    },
});
```

This way both ESCAPE and the OK button close the dialog, and then the event listener kicks in and removes the dialog from the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/okucap/7/)*

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
      // ESCAPE key pressed
      if (e.which == 27) {
         $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
      }
});
```

Comment: This would work if you want to keep your jquery-ui file as original as possible. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2):

## **Destroy the Dialog from the DOM:**

**$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()**

### Explanation:

This code will destroy the dialog and remove the Div which one is having the dialog from the DOM.

For example:

I have a dialog box named as $('#report_dialog'), I want to remove the element from the DOM

so I can use the statement like,

```
  **$('#report_dialog').dialog('destroy').remove();**
```

**Destroy the Dialog from the DOM While pressing Esc Key:**
 ========================================================

```
I just Want to override the **closeOnEscape** event in jquery dialog.


$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.which == 27) {
        $('#report_dialog').dialog('destroy').remove();
    }
});
```

We can use the key code exactly or else **$.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE** It will take the the key code automatically and successfully removed from the DOM